# Enterprise Library exception logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

Is it possible to configure Enterprise library to actually log the actual sql statement which is causing the exception?

We have an application which randomly throws a timeout exception in the production environment and I am trying to find out what actually was the sql statement executed which failed with the timeout error. Any sample configuration?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depends on how that SQL statement is *created*.  How does the code invoke the database?  You can log any value that's available to the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to that specific piece of logic. Its an application for students to register courses and some part of it are calling a compiled component which does the business logic. However that component throws a timeout error randomly. Apparently when some other user is performing some different acitvity.

So I am trying to find out which table the component was using when it fails so I can further narrow down the issue.